# How to get short description of grouped product

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I tried to display the short description of a grouped product in grouped.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
            <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>    
                    <div class="custom-box"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getShortDescription()) ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

But nothing is displayed like this.
Any idea why?

Comment: is it magento2 or magento 1?

Comment: magento2. The code is working but the short description is not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_assosicatedProducts` does not holds all the informations like short description. `$_item` holds only following informations

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 33
    [attribute_set_id] => 13
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => 24-WG085
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2017-04-20 10:17:40
    [updated_at] => 2017-04-20 10:17:40
    [inventory_in_stock] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [is_salable] => 1
    [link_id] => 1
    [position] => 0
    [qty] => 0.0000
    [name] => Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot
    [price] => 14.0000
)
```

You can retrieve the product short description by loading explicitly with the help of ID / SKU.

Comment: i know few data only getting from that array. I need short_description of the array.